# How to make Tabs in android web browser

Tags: android, webview, tabs

I'm making an android browser app (with  webviews), but am facing a problem, I don't exactly know how to make tabs for new windows... Is it with fragments ? Thank you so much. 
Sam Panagrosso

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your question, as currently worded, is likely to get closed since you need to show that you've done your due diligence first (see #3 under the [off-topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of what you can ask on SO).  If you can edit your question to show that you've researched how to create tabs in Android and also include an attempted code solution, we can help you further from there.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use FragmentTabHost in order to make Tabs.

Use FragmentTabHost inside that TabWidget then finally TabsContent i,e FrameLayout int the main LayoutFile.

Then you can use one fragment with WebView in the layout file for the Fragment.

An then by Using FragmentTabHost class you can create tabs.